# mFailed parsing a text file

Tags: python, algorithm, parsing, python-3.x

I have a set of words in  following form.
`(journalistic (((journalism:stem)ist:suffix)ic:suffix)`).  I am trying to parse the  into following form

```
    root- journalistic  
    stem suffix suffix
    stem -  journalism
    suffix -ic
    suffix -ic
```

The code, I use 
    from itertools import takewhile

```
is_tab = '\('.__eq__

def build_tree(lines):
    lines = iter(lines)
    stack = []
    for line in lines:
        indent = len(list(takewhile(is_tab, line)))
        stack[indent:] = [line.lstrip()]
        print (stack)

source = '''
(journalistic (((journalism:stem)ist:suffix)ic:suffix))'''

build_tree(source.split('\n'))
```

It produce the output:

```
['']
['(journalistic (((journalism:stem)ist:suffix)ic:suffix))']
```

The code is not segmenting the word sequence. 
Any code fixes ?

Comment: Your code is not sufficient to parse the strings in following form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you are looking for python help, but you can also write a simple PERL script to get the output.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
while(my $ln = <DATA>) {
  chomp $ln;
  my($root, $rest) = $ln =~ m/\((.*?)\s+(.*)\)$/;
  print "Root - $root\n";
  if($rest) {
    my @pairs = $rest =~ m/(\w+\:\w+)/g;
    my @v;
    my @a;
    map {my ($k, $v) = split(/\:/, $_); push @v, $v; push @a, [$k, $v]} @pairs;
    print "@v\n";
    map {print "$$_[1] - $$_[0]\n"} @a; 
  }
  print "=====\n";
}

__DATA__
(journalistic (((journalism:stem)ist:suffix)ic:suffix))
```

Output:

```
Root - journalistic
stem suffix suffix
stem - journalism
suffix - ist
suffix - ic
=====
```

Answer (score 1):

`pyparsing` includes the function `nestedExpr` to simplify the parsing of nested list elements:

```
source = '''
(journalistic (((journalism:stem)ist:suffix)ic:suffix))'''

from pyparsing import nestedExpr

print nestedExpr().parseString(source)[0].asList()
```

prints:

```
['journalistic', [[['journalism:stem'], 'ist:suffix'], 'ic:suffix']]
```

**EDIT**

You can see the contents of the nested list using code below:

```
parsed = nestedExpr().parseString(source)[0].asList()
print (parsed[0])  # this looks like it would be the root
print (parsed[1])  # will have to walk this recursively to extract the other bits
print (parsed[1][0])

# how to walk the nested list recursively...
def dump_tree(t, indent=''):
    for s in t:
        if isinstance(s, list):
            dump_tree(s, indent + '  ')
        else:
            print (indent + '- ' + s)
dump_tree(parsed)
```

Prints:

```
journalistic
[[['journalism:stem'], 'ist:suffix'], 'ic:suffix']
[['journalism:stem'], 'ist:suffix']
- journalistic
      - journalism:stem
    - ist:suffix
  - ic:suffix
```

Comment: It did not parse the tree. It just changed the bracket

Comment: Look again. The value returned by `asList()` is not just a string with '()'s changed to '[]'s. It actually is a nested list of strings and lists.

Comment: How can I return the stuff in following form ?
oot- journalistic - 
stem suffix suffix
    stem -  journalism
    suffix -ic
    suffix -ic

Comment: You will have to learn how to manipulate data that is returned as a nested list. I've shown you examples of how to access the individual elements, you should be able to take it from there.

Comment: @Karun Take some effort instead of asking  everything.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire Thanks for the great package. If I have prefixes, it can handle it or not ?

Comment: It can. Try it and see - hope you enjoy using pyparsing!